# Angular Catch HTTP Status Code

Tags: angular

I have a service class that makes a HTTP POST call to a REST server. The server responds on an error with HTTP status codes, like 404 if the resource does not exists, 401 if the user has no access to this resource, and so on.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class BacklogService extends RestService {

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
        super();
    }

    public create(
        projectId: number,
        type: string,
        description: string,
        isReady: boolean,
        estimation: string | null) {

        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.getToken());
        const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        return this.http.post(this.getRequestUrl('Project/' + projectId + '/Backlog'), {type: type, description:description, isReady: isReady, estimation: estimation}, options).subscribe(
            (response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
            },
            (error: Error) => {
                // error.status doesn't work
                console.log("error=", error);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

I tried to catch these HTTP status codes in the error case. If I output the error variable it contains the right data, which I expected, but I do not have access to this object and its keys. Accessing `error.status` does not work.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't work"*? You don't seem to be *trying* to access it. What happened when you did?

Comment: So it might come as a shock but a 404 or the like does not throw an exception like you are trying to catch. Instead you check the response object `response.status` and then do something about it. You also don't `.subscribe()` in your service definition. That's a job for the code that consumes your service. So your service methods should just be returning `Observable`.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, your comments helped me with my problem. Now the service returns a Observable and in the Component I use the subscribe function.